# How can I use the bx ml generate-manifest libraries in watson machine learning

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I've built a deep learning model that uses for pre-processing purposes a custom library called `Augmentor` and I would like to include it when running on `Watson Machine learning` service on the cloud.

For now I am using a workaround in my code which uses `pip` to install the library:

```
import pip

def install(package):
    if hasattr(pip, 'main'):
        pip.main(['install', package])
    else:
        pip._internal.main(['install', package])

try:
  import Augmentor
except:
  install("Augmentor")
  import Augmentor
```

I've been looking at the command line interface `bx ml` and I noticed that there is a command line `bx ml generate-manifest libraries` which generates libraries.yml:

```
name: libraries_custom
description: custom libraries for scoring
version: '1.0'
platform:
  name: python
  versions:
  - '3.5'
```

I would like to know if this is the right why to declare custom libraries required to run my code on WML ? 
I can't find any documentation on this anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for as, I am aware of you can create custom components using generate-manifest of ibmcloud CLI

```
bx ml store libraries thepyfuncpackage-0.1.zip library.json
```

You can find the complete instructions [here](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/ml-custom_libs_tensorflow.html)

If you want to install additional libraries to support your work, you must create a wheel (.whl) file and include this with the .zip file that you submit as part of your training run or experiment. You can then execute them by running the pip install /.whl command.

Complete instructions [here](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/ml_dlaas_3rd_party_install.html)

Hope this is helpful